# How to check the date type in array in PHP

Tags: php, phpexcel, codeigniter-3

I'm using PHPExcel to read the data, and then validating the data. Problem I'm getting is all the data is validating except I don't know how to check the array if it has a date or not. Problem is not a format, problem is I'm unable to find a way to check whether it is a date or another string or integer. These are one of my value in a date cell in Excel file. i.e ;

```
1/2/15 17:24
1/7/15 12:00
1/9/15 11:57
```

Comment: Use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19958292/php-check-multiple-dates-in-array-are-within-a-date-range

Comment: @Veritasian i thinnk you havent read my question. Problem is not a specific format or a range. I just want to know it is a date or not.

Answer (score 0):

For each cell you can check if this is a date :

```
if(PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($cellobj)) {
    //it's a date
}
```

Comment: Ok i m trying this!

Comment: No, it doesn't work on a cell value; that's why the argument is `$cellobj`, because it requires a cell object

Answer (score 0):

you have to check your current version of PHP because new functions are not available in old versions. Is you date format is fixed? if yes then there is function `checkdate ().` it returns true on valid date.

```
bool checkdate ( int $month , int $day , int $year )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php

Checks the validity of the date formed by the arguments. A date is considered valid if each parameter is properly defined.

My suggestion is, `explode()` 1/2/15 17:24 data from excel and then pass it to the `checkdate()` function, if it returns true then this is "DATE"  or this entire excel column contains DATE

Comment: this does not work. I have thousands of cells in the date column and in each cell value. It takes so much time to explode and then pass it to the checkdate function.

Comment: get all csv data in an array and then process it! I have used PHPExcel on millions of records! or can you run this php script from command line? If you are running it through the webpage then you have to make some configuration changes for memory, array max length, execution time, priority of the job etc...

Comment: ok so in each value of cell. After exploding can you just guide me how to put every value to match with the checkdate variables like $month , $year, $date