# How to check date type in a variable in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime, phpexcel

I have an array in which dates are likes `01/10/2015 22:53:00`  or `08/19/2016`. i want to check that whether it is a date or not. If somebody put a text or other type in the field(Excel array), which i am putting into a variable, then it should generate an error that this is not a date.

I have searched but did not found success. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could do `strtotime($value)` and check if the result is `false`

Comment: i have checked that it gives false on putting a text like 'anybody there' but if i put 'a' along side my date '08/19/2016'  it gives a time stamp. Any idea about it?

Comment: try preg_match :)

Comment: @ArkadiuszG. can you provide me a link about it. Sorry to say but i am not very skillful in regular expressions.

Comment: @adeel What I would do is: `$ts = strtotime($value); if ($ts !== false) { $value = date("format you want", $ts); }` which will reformat your date to whatever you want if PHP can infer a valid date from the input. I don't think it matters if there's a few extra characters around as long as you can remove them and make your date format consistent (which will make things easier for you when you later read the file.

Comment: @apokryfos actually this does not work i have looped through array and pass the value to strtotime but this is not giving me error.

Comment: How do you create this array of values? Where do you want to validate if it is a date or not? Your question (like the [previous one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41956979/how-to-check-the-date-type-in-array-in-php)) is very unclear about what you are trying to do

Comment: @MarkBaker Sorry previous one was not a clear question i agree! . Actually  there is a column of date in my excel file i m getting formatted values from that column and checking whole column whether it contains other values than date. If true then give a error to jquery if false then submit the excel column of date to the database.

Comment: You need to check each cell as you read it, using `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($cellObject)` to identify if a cell contains a date/time value

Comment: @MarkBaker Can i apply this on a value actually i m getting value from each cell. Correct me if i am wrong. This is my progress so far. 
`$date=$worksheet->getCell('C' . '2')->getFormattedValue();
PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($date)`

Comment: No! PHPExcel needs to be able too read the cell's format mask to identify a date/time value... MS Excel store dates as a float, no different to any other float; it's the format mask that differentiates it as a timestamp value, and that information comes from the cell. Your `$date` value is nothing more than a standard PHP string value, that has no special meaning

Comment: Use `if PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($worksheet->getCell('C' . '2')) { echo 'I am a date/time'; } else { echo 'I am not a date/time'; }`

Comment: @MarkBaker Thankx much help provided. It is a simple function. This is also worked and i tried the Arkadiusz G. that also worked with the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (simple preg_match):

```
//your date
$date = '01/10/2015 12:12:23';

//check format
if(preg_match("/^[0-9]{1,2}\\/[0-9]{2}\\/[0-9]{4}$/", $date) OR preg_match("/^[0-9]{1,2}\\/[0-9]{2}\\/[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}\\:[0-9]{2}\\:[0-9]{2}$/", $date)) {
    echo 'OK';
}else {
    echo 'BAD';
}
```

Comment: i m checking this.

Comment: G i have checked this. Problem is date field contains 1/2/2016 and also `01/2/2016`. So it meant for the date i have to mention the both cases for the only '1' and for the '01'

Comment: so in another value i have to add another number in the second value. {1,2}. ?? 
Dont mind if i sounds silly i know nothing about regex :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules(
    'date', 
    'date time', 
    'regex_match[(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3(0|1))-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-\d{4}]'
);
```

Comment: its not a form validation i m checking against a huge array of an excel sheet