# How to change/reset PHP array type?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following PHP code working to identify intersections of dates that fall on dates where we have a Full condition.

Based on this StackOverflow post : [php check multiple dates in array are within a date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19958292/php-check-multiple-dates-in-array-are-within-a-date-range) I have a working filter using a test array ($d2).

```
<?php

$d2 = array ('08/23/2019','08/24/2019','08/25/2019','08/26/2019','08/27/2019','08/28/2019','08/29/2019','08/30/2019','08/31/2019','09/01/2019');

$start = strtotime('08/27/2019');
$end =   strtotime('08/29/2019');

foreach($d2 AS $date) {
    $timestamp = strtotime($date);
    if($timestamp >= $start && $timestamp <= $end) {
        echo "The date $date falls on a day where we are sold out \n";
    } else {
        // echo "Process Reservation \n";
    }
}
?>
```

The print_r($d2) that works looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 08/23/2019
    [1] => 08/24/2019
    [2] => 08/25/2019
    [3] => 08/26/2019
    [4] => 08/27/2019
    [5] => 08/28/2019
    [6] => 08/29/2019
    [7] => 08/30/2019
    [8] => 08/31/2019
    [9] => 09/01/2019
)
```

But my array which is comprised of checking existing dates, then finding which have x number of instances on a particular date. For instance, if we have 7 or more we have a full condition (sold out).

```
$sold_outUS = array_filter($datesUS, function($n) { return $n >= 7; });
```

If I print_r($sold_outUS) this array, it shows a different type of array structure:

```
Array
(
    [08/23/2019] => 7
    [08/24/2019] => 7
    [08/25/2019] => 7
    [08/26/2019] => 7
    [08/27/2019] => 7
    [08/28/2019] => 7
    [08/29/2019] => 7
    [08/30/2019] => 7
    [08/31/2019] => 7
    [09/01/2019] => 7
)
```

How do I change the way this array is stored so it matches the working state and what is happening that I need to learn?

Looks as though I need an independent key and value for each instance in the array. Just don’t know how to change or reset the array to be? non-multi-dimensional?

Comment: You just want the keys of that array? Use `array_keys()`.

Comment: what is the value of `$datesUS`?

Comment: In the examples, there are two different results shown. The working version is a simple array that shows the default numeric key and the unique value which is a date. The one the does NOT work looks to be a single key then each Date and the qty (=> 7) which is not needed.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You want to know how to create an array that holds multiple values for each date?

Comment: Your array is not multidimensional, so why are you asking how to make it non-multidimensional? Did you mean "non-associative"?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you just need `$dates = array_keys($sold_outUS);`, but the question is too confusing to post that as a real answer.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. My goal is to have the array $sold_outUS be structured like $d2.  @Barmar Yes, your suggestion to use "array_keys($sold_outUS)" worked perfectly!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `array_keys` to get the keys of an associative array.

```
$sold_outUS = array_keys(array_filter($datesUS, function($n) { return $n >= 7; }));
```